# How to access a subclass method from parent method?

Tags: python, inheritance, methods, subclass, super

I’m trying to call a method found within a subclass from the class it inherits from.

```
class Account:
  def __init__(self, full_name):
    self.full_name = full_name
    
class Transactions(Account):
  def __init__(self, full_name, amount=0):
    super().__init__(full_name)
    
    self._transactions = []
    
  def add_transaction(self, amount):
    if not isinstance(amount, int):
      return ValueError('Please use an int.')
    self._transactions.append(amount)
    
acc_0 = Account('Forest Whitaker')
```

I want to call the function ‘add_transaction()’ using acc_0’s info. Not sure if I’m overthinking but how would I go about this?

sidenote: if anyone is familiar with rbx.lua, in this situation I’d be trying to do something like this: acc_0.Transactions.add_transaction(50)

Comment: This is not what inheritance is for. A concrete instance of `Account` has no `add_transaction` method because it's not a `Transaction`. The inheritance hierarchy you've created says "every transaction is an account" but *not* the reverse

Comment: acc_0 = Account('Forest Whitaker', '12/9/2000', 9) should give you an error, Try using the Transactions class instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are instantiating an `Account`, you can't access any transactions, because that class doesn't implement that functionality.  You would need to instantiate the subclass `Transactions`, eg:

```
acc_0 = Transactions('Forest Whitaker', 9)
```

There are actually several problems with your code above, but the subclassing isn't really right for this job anyway.. it's a classic "is a" vs "has a" object oriented problem:  Do transactions HAVE an account, not really.. Is transactions a type of account??  No, not right either.  But, does an account HAVE transactions?  Yes, it does.  So an instance of Transactions should be a member of Account.  So:

```
class Account:
  def __init__(self, full_name):
    self.full_name = full_name
    self.transactions = Transactions()

class Transactions:
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
    self._transactions = []
    
  def add_transaction(self, amount):
    if not isinstance(amount, int):
      return ValueError('Please use an int.')
    self._transactions.append(amount)
    
acc_0 = Account('Forest Whitaker')
acc_0.transactions.add_transaction(9)
```

Answer (score 0):

The inheritance hierarchy is wrong looking at what you are trying to achieve. That should be other way around.

```py
class Transactions:
  def __init__(self):
    self._transactions = []
    
  def add_transaction(self, amount):
    if not isinstance(amount, int):
      return ValueError('Please use an int.')
    self._transactions.append(amount)
    

class Account(Transactions):
  def __init__(self, full_name):
    super().__init__()
    self.full_name = full_name
    
acc_0 = Account('Forest Whitaker')

# now you can call
acc_0.add_transaction(10)
```

Comment: Appreciate it sm.

Answer (score -1):

I’m trying to call a method found within a subclass from the class it inherits from.

```
class Account:
  def __init__(self, full_name):
    self.full_name = full_name
    
class Transactions(Account):
  def __init__(self, full_name, amount=0):
    super().__init__(full_name)
    
    self._transactions = []
    
  def add_transaction(self, amount):
    if not isinstance(amount, int):
      return ValueError('Please use an int.')
    self._transactions.append(amount)


**acc_0 = Transactions('Forest Whitaker')
acc_0.add_transaction(120)**
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35530345)